# Highchart Columns on do not touch x axis

Tags: highcharts

I am generating some column charts using HighCharts. 
Everything works fine but sometime columns do not touch x axis. Please see the screenshots. 
Please suggest some solution so that charts look fine

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? It should work. Maybe you are using some old version of Highcharts?

Comment: Figured out the problem. Labels are too close to each other that columns hang in air. Just lowercasing the labels solved the problem.